# Unflatten in pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I need to change the shape of tensor from [2, 48, 196] to [2, 48, 14,14]. I read there a "unflatten" in pytorch. But I couldn't understand how to use  it.
Is there any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is example for your question.

```
import torch

input = torch.randn([2,48,196])
unflatten = torch.nn.Unflatten(2, (14,14))
output = unflatten(input)
```

If you check output.shape, the shape is [2,48,14,14].

[Unflatten function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unflatten.html) is to expand specific dim to a desired shape. In your case, you want to expand the shape 196 in "dim 2" to new shape of the unflatten dimension "(14,14)".

There are two parameters in Unflatten function.

1. First parameter is **dim**. it is specific dimension which you want to
   be unflatten. In your case, it is 2.
2. Second parameter is **unflatten_size**. It is the new shape of the unflatten dimension of the tensor. So it is (14,14).

Therefore, your Unflatten function should be looked like `unflatten = torch.nn.Unflatten(2, (14,14))`

Comment: I got: module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'Unflatten'

Comment: @user836026 what is your torch version? maybe your pytorch version does not have Unflatten class.

Comment: torch version: 1.4.0

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: @user836026 I don't think your torch version has this module. you need to upgrade your torch version if you really need to use this module. Currently, the torch version is 1.12

Comment: I'm using a shared machine. So I cannot upgrade.  Is there another way, for example using numpy?

Comment: @user836026 you can also use `input = torch.randn([2,48,196]).numpy() ; output = input.reshape(2,48,14,14); output_torch = torch.from_numpy(output)`

Comment: @user836026 You certainly don't need to convert to numpy to reshape a tensor. Use [`Tensor.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.reshape.html#torch.Tensor.reshape) instead to avoid breaking the computation graph.